# Surface Intersection Line integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How do I calculate

$$\int_C ydx+ zdy + xdz$$

Where $C$ is the curve of intersection of two surfaces $$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 =2(x+y) \text{ and } x+y=2,$$
 clockwise when viewed from origin ?

I tried to parametrize the curve as $x=t$, but my biggest problem is to find the interval of integration. I saw a solution for this problem, where the author found $t$ going from $-2$ to $0$ when $z$ is positive and from $0$ to $2$ when $z$ is negative.

Comment: The curve is a circle, isn't it ?

Comment: I think so, but what does the Line Integral represents in this case? The area of this circle?

Comment: No, it's just a line integral with no specific geometric interpretation. You can probably parameterize the circle using spherical coordinates.

Comment: Stokes theorem allowed ?

Comment: Thanks for help, could solve it just by drawing.